# Is it possible to only select a joint, not the entire bone, while in pose mode?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I know that in edit mode it is possible to select & move a joint, but whenever I switch to pose mode, I am no longer allowed to select just the joint and instead the entire bone is selected. Is it possible to just isolate my selection to the joint and move this individually, and if so how can I go about doing that? Hopefully the below image illustrates what I am trying to achieve, I just want to select and move the circled green joint, and not the entire bone.

Thank you in advance!

**How can I just select the green circled joint in pose mode?**
[image: How can I select just the green circled joint?]

**The below image is in Edit Mode, but this is essentially what I want to do in Pose Mode.**
[image: This is desired]

**Since I can only select the bone, it seems I have to rotate the bone up, which now causes me to select the bone to the left and rotate it back down? *This is what I want to avoid doing.***
[image]

Comment: But if you moved the joint the bone would move too. Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati sure. It is fine and desired for the bone to move along with the joint, I'm just hoping to get more control of the pose by moving the joint only instead of the bone.

Specifically, I want the green circled joint to move up in the Z direction while the connected adjacent bones remain where they are (this means the bone with a red 'x' would now angle upwards). If I can only move the whole bone, and not just the joint, it seems like I would have to rotate that bone up, then select the bone to the left and rotate that bone back down to counteract. Hopefully that is clear?

Comment: You could do it with a Spline IK and an empty or another armature to control the points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the joint, bones have to stretch along their Y axis. This behaviour can be obtained with this setup, in which every deforming bone has one constraint to copy the location of a control bone and another constraint to stretch to the following control bone.

[image]

Comment: This is a neat trick! Thank you for the help, it definitely allows me to do what I was wanting to do in my original post.